# How to add parent tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My current *code* is this

```
<div id="parent">
   <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
   <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
   <div class="child3">Child 3 Contents</div>
</div>
```

I want like this using *jquery*

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
    <div id="newparent">
        <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
        <div class="child3">Child 3 Contents</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#parent').children().not(':first').wrapAll('<div id="newparent"/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yfkTv/

Answer (score 1):

another way of doing this

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PcFMH/)

```
$('#parent').children(':gt(0)').wrapAll('<div id="newparent"/>');
```

[.gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

[.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)